# Conditional in clausure where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need a conditional parameter in my clausure where on my procedure.

I know the clausure IF doesnt work on WHERE. What alternatives ?

My code below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC1

 @DATA1 DATETIME, 
 @DATA2 DATETIME,
 @AGE INT = NULL

 AS 
 SELECT ID, DATA, NAME, AGE
 FROM TBL
 WHERE DATA BETWEEN @DATA1 AND @DATA2

 IF(@AGE <> IS NULL)
 AND AGE = @AGE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (@AGE IS NULL OR AGE = @AGE)
```

If @AGE is null then this will always return TRUE.  Otherwise, the AGE need to equal @AGE.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be

```
SELECT ID, DATA, NAME, AGE
 FROM TBL
 WHERE DATA BETWEEN @DATA1 AND @DATA2
AND (@AGE IS NULL OR AGE = @AGE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use CASE here:

```
SELECT ID, DATA, NAME, AGE
 FROM TBL
 WHERE DATA BETWEEN @DATA1 AND @DATA2 and ISNULL( @AGE, 0) = 
   CASE 
      when @AGE IS NOT NULL 
        then AGE 
        else 0  
   end;
```

For @AGE = NULL last condition will be optimized to 0=0 which is always TRUE and optimizer execution plan will be better, cause wont be necessary access to AGE table column.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC1

 @DATA1 DATETIME, 
 @DATA2 DATETIME,
 @AGE INT = NULL

 AS 
 SELECT ID, DATA, NAME, AGE
 FROM TBL
 WHERE DATA BETWEEN @DATA1 AND @DATA2
    and (@AGE is null or @AGE = AGE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need to test for not null, because if it's null AGE=@AGE will evaluate will evaluate false, so this will do:

```
 SELECT ID, DATA, NAME, AGE
 FROM TBL
 WHERE DATA BETWEEN @DATA1 AND @DATA2 AND AGE=@AGE
```